# List of well supported unicode characters

Tags: unicode

Is there a list somewhere of which unicode characters are well supported?  I.e. if I used these characters in an application or on a web page, there's a good chance that the user will see what I see, and not a question mark or a square.

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode  This is a good start.  This shows what a number of unicode characters look like on several common platforms.  But this list is limited to emoji.  I'm more interested in things like arrows and mathematical symbols.

Of course, I can always see which characters look good on **my** computer, phone, web browser, favorite font, etc.  But I want to know what will work well for **most other people**, too.

Comment: I actually have the biggest problems with source code and log files.  I have a little more control over the font that I use in my web pages and other *products*.  But the source code and log files will get copied from one tool to the next and I have no way to recommend or know which font people are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know if a Unicode character is assigned you should check the official [Unicode Chart](http://unicode.org/charts/).

Wikipedia has a good list of fonts which cover the most characters. See [Unicode Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) # `List of Unicode fonts`.

Arial is preinstalled on almost every machine and covers a lot of characters. Not to forget [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) from Google - a font collection which covers almost every character you will ever come in touch with.

For a fast lookup of Unicode characters I recommend [Fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fc/index.htm).

> But I want to know what will work well for most other people, too.

I would go with Arial, or Times New Roman, or make your decision platform dependent.